# update field of table

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin

i have field name birthdate in users database
some users birthdate like =

> 2014/02/18

and some others like =

> 2014-02-18

i should use birthdate varchar (10)

so i want change 2014/02/18 to 2014-02-18

```
SELECT `birthdate` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `birthdate` LIKE  '%%%%/%%/%%' REPLACE '%%%%-%%-%%'
```

this code just select users with 2014/02/18

how can I replace that with 2014-02-18 in sql tab?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? You should be storing them as date/datetime fields.

Comment: thanks for help , but i should use varchar(10) because my date in hijri shamsi  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijri_year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an update statement if you want to change the data:

```
update users
    set birthdate = replace(birthdate, '/', '-')
    where birthdate like '%/%/%';
```

You should, however, learn to store dates as dates and not as strings.

Comment: thanks for help , but i should use varchar(10) because my date in hijri shamsi  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijri_year

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace `/` with `-` you can do comparison like this:

```
SELECT `birthdate` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE replace( `birthdate`, '/', '-' ) LIKE  '2014-02-18'
```

Otherwise, remove both `/` and `-` from date field values and compare for `YYYYMMDD` formatted value.

```
SELECT `birthdate` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE replace( replace( `birthdate`, '/', '' ), '-', '' ) LIKE  '20140218'
```

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE '20140218'` instead `= '20140218'`?

Comment: Well, that is an exact match, I know. That is just an example and can modify the input value with a wild card for search.

Comment: After all since date become as string that will never be used as index and needs a tmp table copy for order/searches - the result will be the same.

Comment: True. When applied string functions on dates in where clauses, it is an overhead and index on date if any defined will not come into picture. Better always define date specific data types to store date and time values.

Comment: thanks for help , but i should use varchar(10) because my date in hijri shamsi en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijri_year

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function

```
replace(birthdate,'/','-')
```